# How to make distilled water?

Tags: water

Sort of unrelated to cooking, but for steaming my clothes using a steamer, I need something called distilled water. I am completely confused by seeing guides on the internet on how to make it. Could someone give a simple guide for the same?

Comment: For all domestic applications ypu can substitute deionised or demineralised water, which can be bought more readily. For steaming clothes the water condensed by a dehumidifier is also suitable

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about cooking. Our list of topics is to be understood as a whitelist, and questions outside of it, even if they're related in some ways to a kitchen, are not accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distilled water has the minerals, salts, and other impurities removed.  To make it, you need to turn water into steam, then condense that steam by cooling it.  That condensed steam is now distilled water.  One way to do this is to partly fill a pot with water.  Float a bowl that is smaller than the pot on the water.  Turn the burner on.  Place the lid of the pot upside down on top of the pot, so that the handle is over the bowl.  Place some ice on top of the now convex lid.  The steam will hit the lid and condense, it will drip into the bowl.  You will have collected distilled water.  However, if you live in a location were you can purchase it at a store, it is both inexpensive, and much easier.

Comment: Actually most of the „destilled water“ you get is demineralized water.  Much less effort and energy than Destillation, but not doable in your typical household kitchen.

Comment: @jmk Yes, and that is why it is recommended in steam producing appliances.